# Java RMI binding problems with dns address

Tags: java, rmi

I'm writing a client-server application which uses RMI. I use dyndns in order to get a immutable address on which I can accept the clients' connections.
But I have some problem in doing the binding operation in the server because I receive this error:
**Connection Refused: connect**

I do the binding operation in this way:

```
MultiServer multi = new MultiServer(); // creates an instance of the remote object
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
Naming.bind("//my_host_address.dyndns.org:my_port/MultiServer", multi);
```

What I need to set up? I've opened the port that I use and configured correctly the dyndns service (I'm sure of it because I use it with socket).

EDIT:

Actually I do something like this in my server:

```
 //other code
 MultiServer multi = new MultiServer();
 System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "hostname.dyndns.org");
 LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2367); // the server will listen on port 2367
 Naming.bind("//localhost:2367/MultiServer", multi);
```

Is it enough? Or I have to specify other information to the client?
On the client side I simply do this:

```
 IRemoteServer remote = (IRemoteServer)Naming.lookup("rmi://hostname.dyndns.org:2367/MultiServer");
```

After this instruction I use normally the method exposed by the remote interface.

But following these steps, I receive this error message:

```
Connection refused to host: **SERVER_INTERNAL_IP**; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

How does it possible that the client when resolve the dns host address, points to the server's internal ip address and not to its real ip?

EDIT2:
I've noticed that the client is able to lookup the server but it's not able to call its remote methods and the exception is raised exactly when, from the client, I try to call a remote method.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'localhost' when binding, rebinding, or unbinding. You can only bind to a registry in the localhost anyway so why use anything else?

However by default the IP address of your host is embedded in your stub, and the stub cannot magically change if your IP address changes. You must set the 'dyndns' hostname into the stub via `java.rmi.server.hostname.`

Comment: I understand this. But how the clients(which will be on other machine with other ip address) can lookup for this server? I imagine that I can't use the same url, but now, in the client part I have to use the dns host address.
Is it right?

Comment: Can you give me a simple example of use?Simply to exemplify what you've written.

Comment: A simple example of setting a system property? `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=XXXX`, or `System.setProperty(...)`. I'm surprised at this request.

Comment: Please see my edit on the main post. I've corrected something, but I still have problems.

Comment: You have to set java.rmi.server.hostname *before* exporting any remote objects. Otherwise the stub has already been created and it is too late.

Comment: I've done what you've suggested and in fact the exception's message has changed because now it's:
Connection refused to host: #CORRECT_DNS_ADDRESS; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Well that's a network connectivity problem. Can you ping that address from that client? Telnet to it?

Comment: Using the dns address I'm not able to connect to it using telnet.
I've opened the port on the router. What Have I missed?

Comment: I'm also not able to ping it.

Comment: So there you are. Not an RMI problem, or a programming problem.

Comment: ...or it's just not responding to ICMP.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the server with:

`java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=yourserver.dyndns.org -Djava.security.policy=yourPolicy.txt -cp 'yourjar.jar' yourServerClass`